# How to deploy pyautogui app on server in headless mode selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui, xvfb

i use selenium with pyautogui for clicking on chrome toolbar extensions .
it work propely in local
but when add headless it didnt work i even use xvfb-run on server and another library in python for virtual screen display but not effect!

```
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
while 1:

    try:
        e=pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img.jpg', confidence=0.65)
        print ("I can see it")
        break
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        print("I am unable to see it")
    time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.moveTo(e[0], e[1], 1)
pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the driver.maximize_window() function from selenium's web driver and add_argument(--headless) together.

Comment: i've used max window but problem is another thing , pyautogui cant work on server properly !  even i use headless it couldnt find image in virtual screen (i use xvfb to simulate a virtual screen in headless mode)